# How can a white box test fail, and a black box test succeed (and vice versa)?

Tags: testing, black-box-testing, white-box

I have an exam and trying to find an answer to this question but I am unsuccessful so far. Question is:

> Give an example white box test says everything okay but black box
>   test says there is an error. And an example black box test says
>   everything okay but white box test says there is an error.

Comment: There does not seem to be a question in all this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that with 'black box test' you mean some sort of integration test (ie. only use the public visible UI), and that with 'white box test', you mean some sort of unit test (ie. exposing the technical internals):

Consider a scenario where you expect the result shown to the user to be `10`, maybe a calculation for an invoice or some such.
This works fine in your integration test, but when you do a unit test, the function responsible for getting `10` is actually returning `9`!
A reason this might happen is that the integration test is running a lot more code than just the unit test, for example, you might do:

```
def _function_responsible_for_10
   return 9
end

def output_to_user
  value = _function_responsible_for_10()
  return value + 1
end
```

See the `return value + 1`? This gets you the correct output, but you get it in the wrong way. This only *happens* to work in this scenario, but when you add more code relying on `function_responsible_for_10` later on (or change `output_to_user`), you suddenly get different (unexpected) results. Perhaps even worse, you could fix `_function_responsible_for_10` at some point to correctly return `10`, which will actually break this code!

The example is simplified, and this is just *one* problem that might occur, but it should get you thinking in the right direction :-) I encourage you to think of other (possibly better!) examples your self.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understand the idea. I will try to find examples based on this one.